# How to print numpy matrix nicely with text headers? python

Tags: python

How can I print matrix nicely with headers like this:

```
      T  C  G  C  A
  [0 -2 -4 -6 -8 -10]
T [-2  1 -1 -3 -5 -7]
C [-4 -1  2  0 -2 -4]
C [-6 -3  0  1  1 -1]
A [-8 -5 -2 -1  0  2]
```

I have tried to print with `numpy.matrix(mat)`, But all I have got was:

```
[[  0  -2  -4  -6  -8 -10]
 [ -2   1  -1  -3  -5  -7]
 [ -4  -1   2   0  -2  -4]
 [ -6  -3   0   1   1  -1]
 [ -8  -5  -2  -1   0   2]]
```

And I also didn't succeed to add the headers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pandas` library for that:

```
>>> from pandas import DataFrame
>>> matrix = [(' ', [  0, -2, -4, -6, -8, -10]),
...  ('T', [ -2,  1, -1, -3, -5, -7]),
...  ('G', [ -4, -1,  2,  0, -2, -4]),
...  ('C', [ -6, -3,  0,  1,  1, -1]),
...  ('A', [ -8, -5, -2, -1,  0,  2])]
...
>>> DataFrame.from_items(matrix, orient = 'index', columns = [' ', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'A'])
      T  G  C  A
   0 -2 -4 -6 -8
T -2  1 -1 -3 -5
G -4 -1  2  0 -2
C -6 -3  0  1  1
A -8 -5 -2 -1  0
```